# Core Foundation / Swift 2: result of CFByteOrderGetCurrent()

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, endianness, core-foundation

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I'm banging my head here.

In my Swift 2 code (Xcode 7.2.1) I am using `CFByteOrderGetCurrent()` to get the byte ordering of the local machine.

I can't figure out how to evaluate the result of the function - the 'if' statement in the following fails compilation with

> "type of expression is ambiguous without more context":

```
import Foundation
let byteOrder = CFByteOrderGetCurrent()
if byteOrder == .CFByteOrderLittleEndian {    // compilation fails here
    /* do something */
}
```

From the [CF documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFByteOrder) I was to expecting the result of the function to be an **enum**, but when I try it in a playground it seems to be an **Int** ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CFByteOrder` is a `typealias` of `CFIndex`.

It is an `enum`, which consists of the following values:

```
CFByteOrderUnknown,
CFByteOrderLittleEndian,
CFByteOrderBigEndian
```

Thus, `CFByteOrderLittleEndian` corresponds to `1`.

In order to do the comparison, one may need to do the following:

```
if byteOrder == CFByteOrder(1)
{
    print(byteOrder)
}
```

`1` here corresponds to `CFByteOrderLittleEndian`.

Comment: OK thanks - but is there a way that I can use the symbolic constants? That would be a lot more readable!

Comment: I worked out how to make the comparison with symbolic constants - see below :)

Answer (score 2):

i am using a little bit different trick ...

```
if 1.littleEndian == 1 {
    print("little endian")
} else {
    print("big endian")
}
```

generally

```
let isLittleEndian = 1.littleEndian == 1
```

is true on little endian system, false on big endian system. the advantage is, that it works on all platforms

Comment: I like this approach as it is generic, and it is clear to the reader what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally cracked how to make the comparison using symbolic constants.

If you convert the result of `CFByteOrderGetCurrent()` into a `UInt32` then you can compare it to the raw value of the constants in the enumeration:

```
import Foundation

let hostByteOrder = UInt32(CFByteOrderGetCurrent())

if hostByteOrder == CFByteOrderLittleEndian.rawValue {
    print("little")
}
```

Comment: Someone on another forum pointed out that another way of doing this is to create a **CFByteOrder** value from the raw value of the enumeration - you can then compare this directly: `if CFByteOrderGetCurrent() == CFByteOrder(CFByteOrderLittleEndian.rawValue) { ... }`

Comment: The same poster also pointed out that, as Swift currently only supports little endian platforms, this is a largely academic question! Nonetheless it's been an instructive exercise

Comment: it supports Big Endian systems too.